Error while Building Rust Rocket Docker image
I have followed this suggestion to build a rust docker image. And this is my current Dockerfile:
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef:latest-rust-alpine as chef

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git cmake

WORKDIR /app

FROM chef AS planner
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.lock ./
COPY ./src ./src
RUN cargo chef prepare

FROM chef AS builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json .
RUN cargo chef cook --release
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release
RUN mv ./target/release/my_app ./app

FROM scratch AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/app /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/app"]

But I am getting the following error:
#13 91.72   CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
#13 91.72   thread 'main' panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cmake-0.1.50/src/lib.rs:1098:5:
#13 91.72 
#13 91.72   command did not execute successfully, got: exit status: 1
#13 91.72 
#13 91.72   build script failed, must exit now
#13 91.72   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
#13 91.72 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
#13 98.75 thread 'main' panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cargo-chef-0.1.66/src/recipe.rs:218:27:
#13 98.75 Exited with status code: 101
#13 98.75 note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
#13 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c cargo chef cook --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
------
 > [builder 2/5] RUN cargo chef cook --release:
91.72   thread 'main' panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cmake-0.1.50/src/lib.rs:1098:5:
91.72 
91.72   command did not execute successfully, got: exit status: 1
91.72 
91.72   build script failed, must exit now
91.72   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
91.72 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
98.75 thread 'main' panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cargo-chef-0.1.66/src/recipe.rs:218:27:
98.75 Exited with status code: 101
98.75 note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

I am able to run cargo build --release via the terminal on my computer without any issues

BoringSSL has an interesting build system, which applies git patches to its own source depending on what features have been enabled.  This requires git to be present when building, but from a quick inspection I don't think it's present in the cargo-chef docker image.  Perhaps apk add git in your Dockerfile somewhere before you cargo chef cook?

i will try. but how did it work then for the person that posted the dockerfile

Their project likely didn't depend on BoringSLL.

I added both git and cmake and now I have a new error. Please see the updated question

I ended up with the follwoing setup:
FROM rust:1.76.0-slim-bullseye as build

RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install -y cmake libclang-dev musl-tools git g++

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

# create a new empty shell project
RUN USER=root cargo new --bin app
WORKDIR /app

# copy over your manifests
COPY ./Cargo.lock ./Cargo.lock
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml

# this build step will cache your dependencies
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs

# copy your source tree
COPY ./src ./src

# build for release
RUN rm ./target/release/deps/*
RUN cargo build --release

# our final base
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

WORKDIR app

# copy the build artifact from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/target/release/my_app .

# set the startup command to run your binary
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["/app/my_app"]


